# AWS RDS keep user access with dynamic IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, amazon-rds, aws-security-group

On AWS rds I added few postgres users. There is `Security groups` which needs IP addresses for access to DB instance right?

So if user have static IP address, then I will add that once and there is no problem.

But if user have dynamic address, only way I see is that periodically update IP's for keep users valid connections.

My question is: if there is possible  to keep dynamic IP users valid connections, without manually update security group data ?

Thanks !

Comment: From where (i.e. on-premise/other cloud provider/within same AWS VPC/other) these user's are accessing the AWS RDS DB Instance? 
What DB client tools/applications these users are using to connect to AWS RDS DB instance? Are all these able able to connect to AWS RDS DB instance, with manual steps you specified?

Comment: @amitd - Those users use PGadmin for connecting AWS postgres Instance. If I manually put that user current IP for AWS "Inbound rules", then user can connect to DB. Problem is that, users have dynamic IP's and after some period they getting new values, which does not matchs existed IP on AWS

Comment: @amitd - "From where (i.e. on-premise/other cloud provider/within same AWS VPC/other) these user's are accessing"   They're accessing from outside, from their home.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following are some of the options;

1. [Connect Ec2 using bastion host](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-connect-ec2-bastion-host/).
2. In case, user's are connecting using office network/VPN with fixed **private IP CIDR**, then allow **inbound** for that IP CIDR in the **security group**. Note:* This might open access to wider private network of your organization. RDS will be available from on-premise, only if you have that AWS VPC connectivity from your organization private network.

Answer (score 0):

Building on [@amitd's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14843902/amitd) answer, you can and should use a bastion host however you will still need to open that host up to your dynamic IP. To update the IP address that is allowed to access that host to only my assigned IP I use the following script

```sh
#! /bin/bash

# This script makes it easier to maintain security groups that allow SSH access
# from a computer with a dynamic IP, such as a computer on a home network or ISP.
#
# Using the script will allow you to SSH to an EC2 without having to allow
# access to the whole world (0.0.0.0/0). If you run this script whenever your IP
# changes then the security groups in your account specified by your AWS profile
# will be updated.
#
# The script will find any security groups for your current profile that are
# tagged with a Tag with a Key of "ssh-from-my-ip" and a case insensitive value
# of "true" or "yes".
#
# For each security group found it will revoke any existing tcp ingress on
# port 22 and authorize ingress on port 22 for your current IP.
#
# Dependencies - AWS CLI and jq


# need my current ip
MY_IP=$(curl --silent https://checkip.amazonaws.com)
echo "Your IP is ${MY_IP}"

# need security group id(s) and existing CIDR for the SG
pairs=$(aws ec2 describe-security-groups | aws ec2 describe-security-groups | jq -c '.SecurityGroups[]? | select( (.Tags[]? | select(.Key == "ssh-from-my-ip") | .Value | test("true|yes"; "i"))) | if .IpPermissions | length == 0 then {sg: .GroupId, cidr: null } else {sg: .GroupId, cidr: .IpPermissions[].IpRanges[].CidrIp} end')

for p in $pairs
do
  SG=$(echo "$p" | jq -r '.sg')
  OLD_CIDR=$(echo "$p" | jq -r '.cidr')

  echo "Updating security group ${SG}"
  if [[ $OLD_CIDR != 'null' ]]
  then
    echo "Revoking ingress permission for ${OLD_CIDR} in security group ${SG}"
    # remove the existing ingress permission
    aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress \
        --group-id "${SG}" \
        --protocol tcp \
        --port 22 \
        --cidr "${OLD_CIDR}"
  fi

  # authorize my new IP CIDR
  NEW_CIDR="${MY_IP}"/32
  echo "Authorizing ingress permission for ${NEW_CIDR} in security group ${SG}"
  aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id "${SG}" --ip-permissions '[{"IpProtocol": "tcp", "FromPort": 22, "ToPort": 22, "IpRanges": [{"CidrIp": "'"${NEW_CIDR}"'", "Description": "Rule0"}]}]'
done
```