# AWS Restrict Access But Allow Edit of a Security Group

Tags: amazon-web-services

I work with a team of developers that has a shared database hosted in AWS. This team is "virtual" (comprised of remote workers--there is no officesi).

There is an AWS security group that has rules that allow each of the developers to access the database (by IP address). The senior developers have logins and admin permissions to AWS allowing them to change the security group rules--for example when someone's IP address changes.

The problem is that some of the junior developers have "jumpy" IP addresses which change frequently. Each time the IP address changes, a senior developer needs to stop work, login to AWS, and correct the security group rule for the junior developer. This is not sustainable.

Is there a way we can set up AWS so the junior developers can have logins to AWS, but their permissions only allow them to access a single, particular security group? That way the juniors can login to AWS and self-serve on the IP address update, and management doesn't need to worry that they have access to other, restricted areas in AWS?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65892662/14843902) of use ?

Comment: Yes, actually, it might be. I think the idea is that the team could connect to a VPN with a fixed outgoing IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To directly answer your question, there are multiple ways to achieve what you want and IAM and SCP are the things to take a look at.

With IAM you can either use [IAM Permission boundaries](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-permission-boundaries/) to limit the privileges that a certain user has or rely on the [ABAC approach](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_attribute-based-access-control.html) where you assign a certain tag to the resource to which you want to grant access to. In your case you can have a "junior" tag set on the SG in question and a respective IAM policy that grants permissions based on it.

Another option is to use a [Service Control Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps.html) (in case you have AWS Organization enabled). With SCPs you can limit certain actions on account level (e.g. Deny action on ec2, unless a certain criteria is met).
All of the above are on identity access level.

Networking-wise you can alter your design a bit by setting up an [AWS Client VPN in front of the RDS.](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/accessing-an-amazon-rds-instance-remotely-using-aws-client-vpn/)